# async invoke method in one line

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, lambda

I am simply trying to execute an otherwise blocking method asynchronously in one line in VB.

```vb
Dim action As New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))
action.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

In C#:

```c#
(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Translated to VB

```vb
(New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(nothing, nothing)
```

does not compile. Syntax error when starting the line with a parenthesis.

Any solutions? If yes, what? If no, why not? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this and got no issues:

```
Dim a = (New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ric, that works. Seems so simple. I wonder why they don't let us make an anonymous Action and just BeginInvoke it like in C#

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not too sure as to why. This isn't something that I use but could probably see myself doing something like this in the future. Just need an excuse to do so :)